# How can I extract values in html loop(mustache) when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

all I want to do is make a call by using "idx".
something like this.. alerts/1 alerts/2 alerts/3.....

```
{{#alerts}}
<tr name = "alerts">
    <input name = "idx" style="display : None" value="{{id}}">
    <td><input type="submit" value="start alert" name="alert-start"/></td>
    <td>ticker : {{ticker}}</td>
    <td>price : {{price}}</td>
</tr>
{{/alerts}}
```

So I made a Jquery

```
   $('input[name=alert-start]').on('click', function() { 
            _this.alertStart();
        });
},

alertStart : function() {
    var idx = $('input[name=idx]').val();

     $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/alerts/'+idx,
                    }).done(function() {
                        alert('start alert');
                    }).fail(function (error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    });
},
```

But... with this code, I can only call "alerts/1". No matter how many alerts are there...
What can I do?? Please someone help.. I'm really struggling with this..

Comment: There is `},` closing brackets but not seeing opening brackets . So can you show entire jquery code ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into followings

- `<input name = "idx" type="hidden" value="{{id}}">` is the correct way of hiding any imput from appearing on page
- `$('input[name="idx"]').val();` is correct way to read the idx value

rest seems to be fine look for any error in console

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is pass the input you click on to the `alertStart` function. Then use the object to find the `input[name=idx]` related to the clicked input.

```
$('input[name=alert-start]').on('click', function() {
  _this.alertStart(this);
});

alertStart: function(obj) {
  var idx = $(obj).closest("tr").find('input[name=idx]').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/alerts/' + idx,
  }).done(function() {
    alert('start alert');
  }).fail(function(error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
}
```